# Drupal view - why are all nodes listed, also unpublished ones where user has no right to view?

Tags: drupal, permissions, view

I'm using D7 with the views3-module. No access modules installed.
There is a user with "view published content" and "view own unpublished content".
Also there is a view that simply shows all nodes.

I would assume that Drupal securtiy doesnt show teasers of nodes, that the user has no permission to view.
But in fact all nodes are listed (incl. trimmed summary). When the user clicks on a unpublished node from "root", he gets "access denied".

I already doublechecked that in the view's setting "query settings" everything is unchecked (esp. "disable sql rewrite" is clear).

Can someone help ?

Thanks alot,

Martin

Comment: are you getting access denied for all the views ? or just this one view.

Answer (score 0):

Views *Access Permissions* option are *for the whole views* not for each row. That means that it will print the date from the database and display them if the user has the permission to see the results.